# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'TypeError:

Tags: python

Hi im trying to learn python but i cant seem to figure out what the problem is?

```
# coding: utf8
print ("Hello write name to write your name! ")
name = raw_input("What is your name")
print ("Write age to put in your age")
age = raw_input("How old are you")
Thisyear = int(input("what year is it today: "))
year = str((Thisyear - age)+100)
print (name +" Will be 100 years old in the year " + year)
```

And i keep get this error?

```
File "dsdc.py", line 7, in <module>
        year = str((Thisyear - age)+100)
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str`
```

Comment: `Thisyear` is a variable of type `int` and `year` is a variable of type `str`. You're trying to perform an operation on different data types.

Comment: FYI, you're using python 2 which is a little out of date. Instead I suggest you download a python 3 interpreter, which is more beginner friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `age` comes from `raw_input()`, which returns a string, not an integer, so when you perform numeric operations on it it raises a `TypeError` exception.

You should convert `age` to an integer with `int`:

```
age = int(raw_input("How old are you"))
```